# Router-link binding to b-card image

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application, router, bootstrap-vue

Is it possible to bind router-link to b-card's image attribute which are 
not physically exists,i want to switching link on image click

```
 <b-col lg="3" v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
     <b-card 
      v-bind:title="product.title"
      v-bind:img-src="product.img"
      v-bind:img-alt="product.alt"
      img-top
      tag="article"
      style="max-width: 20rem;"
      class="mb-2">
      <b-card-text>Some quick example text to build on the card title and 
       make up the bulk of the card's content.</b-card-text>
      </b-card>
   </b-col>
```

Is there any solutions without creating 'img' tag manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is best solution i found

```
<b-card no-body
      v-bind:title="product.title" 
      v-bind:img-alt="product.alt"
      img-top
      tag="article"
      style="max-width: 20rem;"
      class="mb-2"
    >
    <router-link :to="/someurl">
    <b-card-img :src="product.img"/> 
    </router-link>
    <b-card-body>
       <b-card-title>CCCCCCCCc</b-card-title>
       <b-card-text>Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up 
         the 
        bulk of the card's content.</b-card-text>
      </b-card-body>
     </b-card>
   </b-col>
```